# Attempt when assigning a variable to add two variables within

Tags: bash

I have tried assigning a variable to calculate two variables using addition but does not work

> XML

```
echo "Enter 1st number"
read num1
echo "Enter 2nd number"
read num2
sum-'expr $num1 + num2'
echo "Summation = $sum"


echo "Enter no"
read num1
if test $num1 -gt 10
then
    echo "Number is greater than 10"
fi

if test $num1 -1t 10
then
    echo "Number is less than 10"
fi
```

However, this error always pops up

line 5: sum-expr $num1 + num2: command not

Please help

Comment: As an aside, `((num > 10))` is shorter and more readable than `test $num -gt 10`, in bash.

Comment: Please add a shebang and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: @JoJO : What is the dash (`-`)  doing after the word `sum`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 errors in your implementation:

```
1. sum-'expr $num1 + num2' --> sum=$((num1 + num2))
2. if test $num1 -1t 10    --> if test "${num1}" -lt 10
```

Here is my suggestion

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter 1st number"
read -r num1
echo "Enter 2nd number"
read -r num2
sum=$((num1 + num2))
echo "Summation = ${sum}"

echo "Enter no"
read -r num1
if test "${num1}" -gt 10
then
    echo "Number is greater than 10"
fi

if test "${num1}" -lt 10
then
    echo "Number is less than 10"
fi
```

Comment: ALWAYS quote all variables with `test` or `[..]`, e.g. `if test "$num1" -gt 10` (otherwise, you cover the issues well) Brace enclosing the variables does NOT protect expansion with whitespace, it simply guards the variable name itself.... There is no replacement for double quoting `:)`

Comment: Updated. I just quickly fixed the issues instead of revising his code. Thanks for your comment! :)

Comment: Post your code in [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to find the issue. You must double-quote `"$num1"`. What happens if the user slips and enters `4 4` or anything else that expands with whitespace? You want to prevent the error `"unary operator expected"`. In ShellCheck you will find the error `"SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting."`

Comment: Thanks for the useful website! I have updated and it should be good now.

Comment: Good deal, you already have my vote. Keep the ShellCheck.net link handy. It is very useful when working with shell scripts (it is very thorough).

Comment: Totally agree! It must be a useful website for bash programming.